# How can I convert the sum of minutes, hours in the 'timelite.js' or 'moment.js'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have array `let times = ['04:20:10', '21:15:10']`. I use method add:
`let time1 = add([times])`. Next I use method str: `str([time1])`. I kept 
`25:35:30`. I would like to receive the following result: `25h 35 min 30 sec`. If the sum would come in at `30:00:00` I would like to receive the result `30h`. In the case of the sum of `00:30:00` I would like to receive a result of `30 min`. In the case of `00:00:20` - the result `20 sec`. How to get such a result in the 'timelite.js' or 'moment.js' library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe could be easier if you just format the time.

```
const formatTime = (time) => {
  const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':')
  return `${hour} h ${minute} min ${sec} sec`
}

const time = '25:35:30'

console.log(formatTime(time))

// 25 h 35 min 30 sec
```

This is just a simple example. To achieve what you want you need to put some more logic, but yeah it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

```
const convert = (time) => {
    const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');

    if (hour !== "00") {
      return `${hour} h ${minute} m ${sec} s`;
    }

    if (minute !== "00") {
      return `${minute} m ${sec} s`;
    }

    return `${sec} s`;
  }

  console.log(convert('00:30:00');

//30 min 00s
```

Comment: if the some response drives you to the answer you should mark it as correct